# Appropriate button label suggestions

Tags: gui-design, buttons, labels

I'm building a suggestions system to provide assistance to course providers when uploading their course advert. We provide assistance around spelling and grammar, language and structure and content. Unfortunately, due to technical constraints, we have been forced to create a system that has to be triggered by the user.

If the user enters some text into the course description field, they have to click a button to see the recommendations. The problem I'm having is finding an appropriate label for this button.

[image]

Currently, the label is 'Check' but I don't think this is clear enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the grammar check websites provide context around the whole webpage that helps to understand what is the "Check" button about. Because of the context of your web page is different, the label on the button should be more descriptive as well.

Based on my research, suggestions would be the following:

- Check my content
- Check my writing
- Check your text
- Grammar check

Additionally, I would suggest providing a tip with a light grey coloured smaller size font to the right of the button, which gives a bit more depth to the action of the "Check" button. Something like "This provides assistance with spelling and grammar, language and structure of your content".

[image: Check content Button]

Here is the research behind:

**Grammarly**

*Grammar Check* in the header and *Check your text* as the button label

[image: Grammarly]

**Grammar.com**

Again, *Free Grammar Check* in the header, but *Check my writing!* as the button label

[image]

**GrammarCheck.me**

*Grammar Check* in the website header and *Check your text* as the button label

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is commonly known as a *filter*, and getting the result obtained from this is generally a button with the label *filter*.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply label the button `Get recommendations` because that's exactly what's happening when the user clicks on it. This way, the cognitive load is minimized and the button conveys directly what it is used for.

Generic terms like "filter" or "check" are too ambiguous and don't make it perfectly clear what will happen when the button is clicked.